# MySQL PDO Count Rows - Can I make this more efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

So, I've been learning PDO. So far, I am not at all impressed, honestly, due to the large amount of code needed to do small tasks. However, I am willing to convert nonetheless if I can get my code to be efficient and reusable.

My question is this: can I make this code any more efficient? By efficient, I mean both A) take up less lines, and B) run faster. I am worried that I am going about this all wrong. However, due to the lack of a `num_rows()` function, I can't think of a better way.

```
try
{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");
    $sth->execute();

    if (count($result = $sth->fetchAll()))
    {
        foreach ($result as $value)
        {
            // Rows returned! Loop through them.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // No rows returned!
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    // Exception!
}
```

Is this written properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as my research has shown, no. There is no way to rewrite this code more concisely or logically--the way it stands is entirely optimized. :) It's easy to use, so that's definitely not a bad thing!

Answer (score 1):

Use [PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to issue a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement

Then, Use [PDOStatement::fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name";
if ($res = $conn->query($sql))
{
/* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
$res->fetchColumn(); //This will give you the number of rows selected//
}
```

Make a general function that does that, and all you need to do is send a `select count` based on your needs. You can make in more general by dividing the $select to more variables.

```
function countRows($select)
{
    if ($res = $conn->query($select))
    {
    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
    return $res->fetchColumn(); //This will give you the number of rows selected//
    }
}
```

Comment: This would require me to run two queries though, correct? One to COUNT(*), and another to actually loop.

Comment: Yes, with the second query you can work with the real results.

Comment: That takes much more code, and makes maintenance more time-consuming as both queries would have to be modified if changes are made. I sure wouldn't want to do that in my applications!

Comment: You can define a general function to count the number of rows, get the `SELECT` statement as a variable and return `fetchColumn();`

Comment: This would still require two queries.

Comment: I think its better doing 1 more query on the MySQL server than halting the Web server with not a must loops.

Comment: The difference is just that I'm using PHP's count instead of calling an extra query and function for that query. Though this may be theoretically more memory-intensive, the convenience and maintainability perks far outweigh the slight memory increase. Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score -1):

No, you need to use PDO's rowCount method.

```
try
{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");
    $sth->execute();

    if ($sth->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        while ($result = $sth->fetch())
        {
            // Rows returned! Loop through them.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // No rows returned!
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    // Exception!
}
```

Comment: This does not work for all databases with SELECT statements, as explained in the PHP documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Of course that is true. If the database itself does not support rowCount, the way you do it is inevitable.

Comment: Yep, but I'm using PDO here. Thanks, though!